# Frameworks for Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Are there any open source frameworks based on Selenium WebDriver in C# that

- Abstract all test and object logic away
- Record actions straight into Selenium Webdriver C# code?

I am thinking of writing a framework (not sure about the recording feature), but maybe it's already been done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

•Abstract all test and object logic away -- must be done manually

Record actions straight into Selenium Webdriver C# code? -- the firefox plugin "selenium ide" can output test steps in C#. You can then use the "page object" design pattern to abstract away the object logic.

Here is the best example of using the "page object" pattern I have found. Example is C#

http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/examples/selenium2-in-net-framework/

Comment: All this info can be easily found in official Selenium docs, but thanks for answering. Selenium IDE translates actions into C# very badly.

Answer (score 3):

C# frameworks for Selenium Webdriver:

https://github.com/ProtoTest/ProtoTest.Golem

https://github.com/ObjectivityBSS/Test.Automation

Answer (score 2):

You can try Seleno:

http://teststack.github.com/TestStack.Seleno

It implements the Page Object pattern. It encourages a separation of concern between the logic of your page and your tests.

You can use the Selenium Firefox plugin to record actions, however in my experience it's only been useful for recording quick scripts to aid in development. The code it generates hasn't been of much use to myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) is a Firefox plugin that allows you to record your browser activity and export it to WebDriver C# code.

Answer (score 0):

i've been looking for something similar for a while and came across this article on sauce labs which helped me quite a bit...
http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/12/selenium-testing-framework-part-3-putting-it-all-together/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This framework does nothing I mentioned, as Page Object model does not abstract test logic away from the code

Answer (score 0):

I have went down this route using the open source [Selenide](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide) framework for java tests.

The fact that there is no de-facto standard selenium framework should be a sign that it isn't probably a good thing to. I would not recommend using a framework, I failed 2 times writing a testing suite because of it.

On the other hand writing a testing suite with very good OOP structure reflecting the webpage you are testing has worked wonders for me.  The key is isolating the actual selenium webdriver code from the tests.  You should very rarely use the reference to driver in tests, but instead initialize objects offering services (e.g. UI actions) representing the page elements you want to interact with and test.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815145/selenium-pageobjects-pattern-and-components) is an ok example of this abstraction using the `FindsBy`method in C#.  The [Page Object Model](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) here is more or less what you should be going for.

It's alot of work to write a meta-application for UI testing instead of just copy and pasting recorded actions into code, but it does lead to more robust, reusable, and valuable tests.