# How to initialize SelectElements while using PageFactory / FindsBy in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am building a Page Object Model in Selenium WebDriver for C#, using the PageFactory.

Unfortunately, I have discovered that the `FindsByAttribute` will not initialize a `SelectElement` (HTML `<select>` tag / dropdown menu). I've happened upon or come up with a few ideas to work around it so far, but none of them is ideal:

1. `PageFactory` and `FindsByAttribute` are `sealed`, so I can't force it to by just inheriting those.
2. Manually instantiating a `SelectElement` from an `IWebElement` in each method is rather messy and duplicative. It also ignores the apparent built-in wait in `PageFactory` and throws `NoSuchElementException`s unless I add a wait every time I do this -- which would require repeating the locator all over the place, defeating (part of) the purpose of the POM.
3. Wrapping each `IWebElement` property with a `SelectElement` property is less messy, but still has the same waiting problem as above.

The best option so far is #3, and writing a wrapper for `SelectElement` that just adds a wait to every method. While this solution will *work*, it will bulk up the code of each page a lot, as instead of this (hypothetical) pretty code:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "MonthDropdown")]
public SelectElement MonthDropdown;
```

I'm stuck with a wrapper wrapper (something I'd rather avoid), and:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "MonthDropdown")]
private IWebElement _monthDropdown;
public Selector MonthDropdown
{
    get { return new Selector(MonthDropdown, Wait); }
}
```

With `Selector` being the `SelectElement` wrapper, that also has to take in the `IWait<IWebDriver>` so it can wait, and instantiating a new `Selector` every time I access it.

Is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Sleepily put in wrong access modifiers. Fixed. Thanks, @JimEvans.

Comment: Thank you so much for this question and answer. +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, there's no "built-in wait" in the .NET `PageFactory` implementation. You can easily specify one in the call to `InitElements` (more on that in a bit). At present, the best option for you would be your option 3, though I wouldn't expose the `IWebElement` member; I'd make it `private`, since the `PageFactory` can enumerate over private members just as easily as public ones. So your page object would look like this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "MonthDropdown")]
private IWebElement dropDown;
public SelectElement MonthDropdownElement
{
    get { return new SelectElement(dropdown); }
}
```

How do you get the actual `IWebElement` when you need it? Since `SelectElement` implements `IWrappedElement`, you can simply call the `WrappedElement` property if you need access to the methods and properties of the element provided by the `IWebElement` interface.

Recent versions of the .NET bindings have restructured the `PageFactory` to be more extensible. To add the "built-in wait" you desire, you could do the following:

```
// Assumes you have a page object of type MyPage.
// Note the default timeout for RetryingElementLocator is
// 5 seconds, if unspecified.
// The generic version of this code looks like this:
// MyPage page = PageFactory.InitElements<MyPage>(new RetryingElementLocator(driver), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
MyPage page = new MyPage();
PageFactory.InitElements(page, new RetryingElementLocator(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
```

Additionally, if you *really* need to customize how things work, you're always welcome to implement `IPageObjectMemberDecorator`, which allows you to fully customize how attributes are enumerated and values set to the properties or fields decorated with those attributes. One of the (non-generic) overloads of `PageFactory.InitElements` takes an instance of an object implementing `IPageObjectMemberDecorator`.

I'll leave aside that proper implementations of the Page Object Pattern as strictly defined shouldn't expose any WebDriver objects outside of each page object. Otherwise, all you're implementing is a "page wrapper," which is a perfectly valid approach, just not what one would call a "page object."

Comment: Always like your answer. Something new to learn. However, what is the logic behind `RetryingElementLocator`? In terms of heavily Ajax pages or Angular would it be helpful to locate element?

Comment: Weird thing is, though I hadn't inspected the PageFactory code to look for a wait, I didn't expect there'd be one, and yet, it does still wait for elements to load.

I know the strict Page Object Pattern doesn't expose elements. They're only exposed now because I'm pretty early in the process of building the POM and find it temporarily convenient.

Comment: Thanks! The `RetryingElementLocator` did save me from having to wrap `SelectElement`. I was hoping there'd be a way to get something cleaner (like `FindsBy` directly on a `SelectElement`), but it doesn't surprise me that there's not. Not that I necessarily need it right now, but would you have any more information about usage of `IPageObjectMemberDecorator`? Even Google only has 10 results for it.